# urls.py not passing url pattern

Tags: django

I've just created a url pattern entry to route things to my registration view but the parameter is not being passed at all even though it's clearly in the URL.

My URL pattern:

```
url(r'^register/(?P<profile_type>\w+/?$)', 'userProfile.views.register'),
```

My view definition:

```
def register(request, profile_type=None):
```

The URL I try to load (not the real one, but an example):

```
http://example.com/register/user
```

When I set a pdb breakpoint right at the beginning of the view, profile_type is None, but the url is http://example.com/register/user

I tried running re.match to see if the regex was wrong, and I got the following:

```
match = re.match(r'^register/(?P<profile_type>\w+/?$)', 'register/user')
match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1004d48a0>
match.groupdict()
{'profile_type': 'user'}
```

Clearly the regex is matching the 'user' part of the URL but it's not getting passed. I would love some help with this.

The urls.py contains other patterns that are similar, and these patterns are working properly:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<profile_id>\d+/?$)', 'userProfile.views.registeredUser'),
```

The view is in the right place and is being called correctly but the parameter is not being passed.

Actually, I have a prior pattern in the file that looks like this:

```
url(r'^register', 'userProfile.views.register'),
```

I think that's getting called before the second pattern and messing things up...

Comment: Please post your **exact** URL pattern. Where is the close bracket? Where is the $ ?. "Markdown" does *not* remove spaces if you follow the formatting instructions which are clearly shown on the editing screen - surround your code with backticks for inline formatting, or indent lines four spaces for snippets.

Comment: Is this entry in the urls.py of the app or the urls.py of the project?

Comment: This entry is in the urls.py of the project. The exact URL pattern is: `url(r'^register/(?P<profile_type>\w+/?$)', 'userProfile.views.register'),`
@DanielRoseman, Markdown did _not_ remove spaces. It _did_ remove the <profile_type> part of the pattern, which is why I added spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I just added to the question part, I had a prior pattern in my file that was messing things up:

`url(r'^register', 'userProfile.views.register'),`

I changed it to:

`url(r'^register+/?$', 'userProfile.views.register'),`

And now everything works fine. /facepalm

Answer (score 0):

Try setting APPEND_SLASH to False in settings. See [that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/) for more details

Comment: Check if userProfile is in INSTALLED_APPS. Check that userProfile contains models.py (it may be empty).

Comment: Remove spaces from your regex, like

url(r'^register/(?P<profile_type>\w+/?$)', 'userProfile.views.register'),). 

I've just tried your example. Everything works, please, update your question with folder structure and your settings.py.

Comment: My regex doesn't actually have spaces in it - I had to add the spaces between the '<' and '>' because Markdown wasn't displaying it correctly. It removed the <profile_type> part of the pattern in my re.match() call.

Comment: No error messages. I got a deprecation warning about context processors but this appears to be unrelated. The context processor at `django.core.context_processors.auth` is deprecated; use the path `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` instead.